# How can I customize Eclipse to look like this?

Tags: eclipse

My current Java professor has customized Eclipse (see screenshot below). I really like the orange highlights, which is why I want to know how to do this myself. Do I have to change some settings, or is this a theme, or is there some completely different way?

Since I'm using both: Is this possible on Windows/iOS, and if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find that in *"Preferences>>General>>Editors>>Text Editors"* under *"Appearance color options"* with color name *"Selection background color"* (See picture). A restart of eclipse may be necessary for it to take effect. Other colors outside the editor you find under "General>>Appearance>>Colors and Fonts".

[image]

Comment: I managed to change the "Selection Background Color", but I can't seem to find the option that changes the color of the selected file in the project explorer and the option to change the color of the selection in the outline...

Comment: Not sure, but I think these are defined by the operating system. You professor probably has installed a theme there.